# Laravel + PHP ENV + Windows 10

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, windows-10

So I have been asked to work on a Laravel 4.2 build on windows 10 pro.
Sadly I can't use the tools I want..

The original build of the site uses a local config that is referenced using the "$_ENV['x']" for each of the DB options in the config/DB file.

However Laravel cannot access this variable on windows 10. I have set the Ubuntu shell and wamp server to (variables_order = "EGPCS") but I cant find a way to allow Laravel to store the config/local/db file in the $_ENV variable...

Does anyone have any solutions to this issue?